# Is it possible to remove mac os completely and install Windows on SSD rather than HDD?

Tags: windows, bootcamp, imac, ssd, hdd

I've used my old iMac (iMac 17,1 late 2015) for about 6 years now, and I've got the new iMac now, so I have been trying to install windows on this old machine.

However, when i use Bootcamp to install windows, it installs it on my HDD, making it unusablly slow and laggy. It literally takes 5 minutes to boot and 30 seconds to open a new program. But the most frustrating thing is that this machine has a SSD!

Is there a way to erase MacOs completely and use the ssd as a boot drive for Windows? I don't care If i have to do a fresh install of windows.

Comment: You have a Fusion drive installed, right?

Comment: Yes I have a fusion drive on my iMac